# autocomplete contact android

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, contacts

I'm having a problem with my autocompletetextview.
I'm trying to get the autocomplete get my contacts. Apparently I have scoured everywhere for tutorials, but as I am a starting Android developer, I'm having a hard time to understand how. So could somebody help me by giving me sample code for autocomplete.

I have already finished this;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

And I have already placed this;

```
AutoCompleteTextView phonenumber; 
phonenumber= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.tosend1);
```

My question is how am I going to get all of my contacts and put it in a list?

I have already used the sample in developer android and it already shows values, but I want to use it using the data from the phonebook. How am I going to put it in contactlist?

```
static final String[] contactlist = new String[] {"value1"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code this is a working one

```
Cursor contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
contactCursor.moveToFirst();
do {
            String num = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            acontactslist.add(num);
            }
        } while (contactCursor.moveToNext());

phonenumber.setAdapter(acontactslist);
```

Comment: How should I declare the acontacts list? like this;                      private List<String> acontactslist;

Comment: acontactslist is an ArrayAdapter<String> or ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>